# Android, accessing internal sound files as resource IDs

Tags: android, resources, audio

I need to send some feedback to user by playing a click sound. I'm trying to use MediaPlayer.create () with built in OGG sound files, mainly  KeypressStandard.ogg.

How do I refer to these files as resource IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody interested in this question, found a solution like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("/system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg") );
mp.start();
```

I fired this inside an AsyncTask where I do my visual feedback chores, in onPreExecute() I draw "selected" state, play click sound and  wait for 300mS. in onPostExecute(), I redraw object and free resources, works very nice, sample code:

```
private class FeedbackHandler extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    mp.release(); // free resources
    mp=null; // help GC
    myDrawUnselectedState(myObject); // draw normal state
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myobjectcontainer);
    iv.invalidate(); // mark UI for refresh
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    myDrawSelectedState(myObject); // draw selected
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mycontainer);
    iv.invalidate(); // mark for refreshing
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("/system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg") );
    mp.start(); // play sound
    SystemClock.sleep(300); // wait a little bit for user to see effect
    }       
}
```

By the way, Effect_Tick.ogg its the one that fires when you press a button. It seems that these file names are pretty much Android standard, found in many different devices signed with Android copyright disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

The files should be in the raw folder and you can refer to it by id with `R.raw.KeypressStandard`

Comment: I know that, I want to use built in sounds like /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg. Any clues?

Comment: I would suggest you to copy that file to your app, as not all the android mobiles come with that sound file... And check the copyright too :).

Comment: Nevermind, found how to do it -> MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg") );

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your device resources you can get them without hard-coding, using RingtoneManager or ToneGenerator.

```
Uri sound_uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
```

You can also look for free audio files on the web. Check this: https://rcptones.com/dev_tones/